# a particular cardinal equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Why this equation is often used and what does it intuitively say ?

$$\lambda^{\aleph_0}=\lambda$$

Here are examples of a usage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It means that there are $\lambda$ functions from $\omega\to\lambda$. When you say it’s “often used” surely you have some examples in mind. It would be easier to give comments as to its importance if you say what examples you are concerned with. (And it’s not always true, in case that’s part of the question.)

Comment: The significance here is that in Cohen forcing $P=\operatorname{Fn}(\kappa,2),$ the size of the continuum in $V[G]$ is $(\kappa^{\aleph_0})^V.$ So, if the ground model satisfies $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$, then since $P$ preserves cardinals, $V[G]$ satisfies $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa.$ This condition comes cheap: if you have a cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality, just go to $L$ and you have $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa.$ So it is consistent that the continuum is any cardinal of uncountable cofinality.

Comment: (On a potentially irrelevant side note, if you're just starting to learn forcing, Shelah probably isn't the right choice.)